# What does it look like when an Instagram user using an iPhone X comes across an iPhone X size image in Stories?

Tags: iphone, design

I am curious to know if someone with an iPhone X could share when an iPhone X style photo comes up in stories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram limits the sizes of the photos that can appear in their stories. Even though you upload for example a high resolution screenshot from an iPhone X, it will be scaled to a lower resolution and even cropped to fit their choice of aspect ratio.

Instagram currently allows for square images (up to 1080x1080 px), vertical images (up to 1080x1350 px) and horizontal images (up to 1080x566px).

It doesn't matter if you're uploading/viewing this on an iPhone X, the same restrictions apply.

Comment: On regular iphone I somtimes see on snapchat that the sides are cut to fit full image, so how would that iphone x style image loop on an iphoen x? I gess insta does not do what snap does interms of allowing teh full iphone x image

Comment: Snapchat and Instagram are two different apps - they can do image processing in two different ways. If you have a follow-up question about Snapchat, please open a new question for that.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343468/what-does-it-look-like-when-an-snapchat-user-using-an-iphone-x-comes-across-an-i @jksoegaard